# A question on a $6 \times 6 $ table(Olympiad question)

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

There are some mines in some cells of a $6 \times 6$ table. Among all $2 \times 2 $ squares, exactly $n$ squares contain an odd number of mines and the rest contain an even number of mines. What is the possible values of $n$ ?

> Here is my try to solve this question :
> For convenience I did it for a $ 4 \times 4 $ table which contains nine, $2\times 2$ squares. In this case suppose the following coordinates are mines : $(1,1) , (1,3) , (3,1) , (3,3)$, in this case all $9$ squares contain a mine, now we could reduce their number one by one forexample at first we add a mine in the $(4,4)$ square, so the number of $2\times 2$ square in which there is the number of odd mines is $8$. In the next step we'll put a mine in the square with $(4,3)$ coordinate in this case two of squares contain the even number of mines, and seven squares contain the number of odd mines.

I think we could continue above solution for solving this question in general, but I'm a little confused. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Did you mean to write, "Among all 2 x 2 squares, exactly $ n $ of them contain an odd number of mines?"

Comment: In the $6 \times 6$ table, From all $2 \times 2$ squares, exactly $n$ ( $ 2 \times 2$ squares) contain an odd number of mines ...

Comment: Okay then edit your post, because "contain the number of odd mines" is wrong and confusing.

Comment: Tnx I did it...

Comment: Your approach is valid, but rather than adding mines, consider removing mines in order to reduce the number of $2\times 2$ regions containing an odd number of mines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We make a much stronger claim.

On a $ (k+1) \times (k+1)$ table, we can fill it up with mines such that any chosen subset of $2 \times 2$ squares contain an odd number of mines, and the rest contain an even number of mines. Hence, all $k^2 $  possibilities (unordered arrangement of squares) are possible.

In addition, all $2^{k^2}$ possibilities (ordered arrangements of squares) are possible.
In addition, there are $ 2^{2k+1}$ ways of doing so for each selection of odd/even squares.

---

Proof:
Let the $ 2 \times 2 $ squares be indexed by the lower left square. IE The $(1,2)$  $2 \times 2$ square comprises of $(1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3)$.
Fill in the $2k+1$ squares of the form $(i, k+1)$ and $(k+1, i)$ (where $i$ is a variable) with mines or not. This gives us $ 2^{2k+1}$ ways. We will show that way will yield chosen subsets of odd/even mines as desired.

Consider the $(k, k)$ $2 \times 2 $ square. This uniquely determines the $(k, k)$ square (based on what we chose for $(k, k+1), (k+1, k), (k+1, n+1)$.
Consider the $(k-1, k)$ $2 \times 2$ square. This uniquely determines the $(k-1, k)$ squares (based on what we have for $(k, k), (k-1, k+1), (k, n+1)$.
Continue by inducting on $(k-i, k)$ to fill out the top row.
Likewise, we can then induct on $(k-i, k-1)$ to fill out the next row, then induct on $(k-i, k-2)$ to fill out the next row, all the way till we induct on $(k-i, 1)$ to fill out the bottom most row.

Comment: What is $i$ ? What is $n$?How could you get $2^{2k+1}$ ?!

Comment: @Reza A) $i$ is a variable. B) $n=k$. C) There are $2k+1$ squares that we're making choices for (to put a mine or not), so there are $ 2^ { 2k+1}$ possibilities. I've edited these in.

Comment: Tnx, How could you get $k^2$?

Comment: @Reza There are $k^2$ $2 \times 2 $ squares in a $ (k+1) \times (k+1) $ board.

Comment: What I mean is that How could you see for $(k+1) \times (k+1)$ table that exactly $k^2$ squares contain an odd number of mines and the rest contain an even number of mines? 
Do you have an exact proof? I could just check it by writing and I couldn't write any short proof for this question!

Comment: @Reza I wrote it up above. Which parts do you not understand? You start off by defining the top and right border, then work your way inwards slowly, 1 $2\times 2$ square at a time.

Comment: I saw your solution and finally I understood what you've done thanks! but I have a question, If we consider your solution how are we supposed to get $k^2$? Could you please explain this in detail to me ? What I mean is that where you calculate that all $k^2$ possibilities there are ? Am I missing something if so, please help me.

Comment: @Reza The questions you are asking do not make clear sense to me, esp if you understood my solution. What do you mean by "how are we supposed to get $k^2$?" (IE $k^2$ what?) Can you specify what you're having confusion with? Are you referring to the 2^k^2 possibilities (ordered arrangements)? Please specify what you're asking.

Comment: We have to count, do you accept this? What I'm confused with is where exactly your solution is counting all  $k^2$ possibilities for $n$ ? You said at first we define the top and right border in $2^{2k+1}$ manner and I understood and then we have to decide for $(k,k)$ $2\times2$ square and I understood and then You said we have to prove this for whole $2 \times 2$ squares and I got it. and I know there are $k^2$ $2\times2$ squares in a $(k+1)\times (k+1) $ table. I just don't get how your solution is counting all $k^2$ possibilities for $n$?!

Comment: @Reza A) What do you mean by "We have to count, do you accept this?"?  B) There are $ k^2 $ $2 \times 2 $ squares, each of which could have an odd number or even number of mines. C) Given any ordered arrangement of what these $2\times 2 $ squares are (of which there are 2^k^2 arrangements) and any ordered arrangement of which border squares contain mines (of which there are 2^(2k+1) ways), my proof shows that we can always complete the square (This way is unique, which I haven't proven).

Comment: Thank you I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the table into four $3\times3$ squares. Each contains four $2\times2$ squares. It is easy to place mines such that precisely $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$ or $4$ of these squares contain an odd number of mines, and none of the remaining $2\times2$ squares contain a mine. This way you get all $n\leq16$.

For $n\geq16$ place mines at the squares that have both coordinates even. This places $9$ mines in a square grid in such a way that every $2\times2$ square contains precisely one mine; omit some of the corner mines to get any number $n\geq16$.

Comment: How did you get $n$?